# How to pass value to query string in PHP? 

Tags: php

I want to pass a uid to the next page through a query string. How do I pass it and how do I get it on the next page?

Comment: add some code , of your problem

Answer (score 2):

> i want to pass a uid to next page
>   through querystring.how i pass it and
>   how i get it on next page?

You can create a link like this:

```
<a href="page.php?var=value">Go</a>
```

The variable-value pair after `?` will create the query string. Later you can get the query string with `$_GET` array like `$_GET['var']` for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass the value from one page to another page using SESSION.

```
session_start();   
$_SESSION['variable name']=$var;
```

**$var** is the variable where you store the value that you want to pass to next page and **variable name** is name of session variable .

In the Next page where you want to fetch.

```
session_start();
$a=$_SESSION['variable name'];
```

**$a** in which you get the value that you store on the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that:

1. For links: pass "uid" as GET parameter in all links: `<a href='something.php?uid=$uid ... '`
2. For forms: pass "uid" as POST parameter, this can be done with `<input type='hidden' name='uid' value='$uid'>`
3. Also, you may use cookies, see the following article for details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 0):

//if your data is not danger and Sensitive information send like this

```
$uid="your variable";
header("location:page.php?uid=$uid")
```

// get like this in another page (page.php)

```
$uid=$_GET['uid'];
```

//if your data is Sensitive information like pass use it

```
$_SESSION['uid']="your variable";
header("location:page.php?uid=$_SESSION['uid']")
```

// get like this in another page (page.php)

```
$uid=$_SESSION['uid'];
```